# Recibo de mi PHP un "false" en vez de la cadena que busco

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Tengo este php:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');

function obtiene(){

    $indice = $_POST['indice'];

    $conec = new mysqli("","","","");
    $dbData = array();

    if($conec->connect_errno){
        $dbData = "ERROR";
        exit();
    }

    $result = $conec->query("SELECT * FROM `Teatro` WHERE `indice` = '$indice'");

    while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
        $dbData[]=$row;
    }

    echo json_encode($dbData);
}

obtiene();
```

y lo mando a llamar con:

```
    var dataT = new XMLHttpRequest();
    dataT.open( "POST", "comandos/obtenerSingleTeatro.php", false );
    dataT.addEventListener("load", function() {
        
        if (dataT.status < 400){

            var puedeSeparar = false;
            console.log(dataT.responseText, que);

            var JSONT = JSON.parse(dataT.responseText);
            var objT = JSONT[0];
            
            var fechasT = objT['Fechas'].split(";");
            var fechasCount = fechasT.length;

            for(var m = 0; m < fechasCount; m++){

                var arregloFecha = fechasT[m].split("/");
                var anio = arregloFecha[2];
                var mes = arregloFecha[1] - 1;
                var dia = arregloFecha[0];

                var fecha = new Date(anio, mes, dia);
                var hoy = Date.now();
                
                if(fecha > hoy)
                    puedeSeparar = true;
            }

            console.log("puede separar ", puedeSeparar);

        }else
            console.log("error al cargar", dataT.statusText)
    });

    dataT.send(que);
```

Estoy consiente de que XMLHTTPRequest es muy desactualizado y que está el ajax, pero ahorita no tengo el tiempo para emigrar todo lo que tengo en mi página a ese formato. Lo que quiero saber es por qué cuando hace la llamada el request, el php me manda por el responseText un "false" (lo imprimí en consola). Ya verifiqué, y si está mandando correctamente el índice que quiero buscar. Como información adicional, Uso Visual Studio Code, mi web está alojada en Hostinger y no sé cómo verificar en consola los pasos del php (creo que investigaré eso mientras). Por su atención, gracias.

NOTA:
Antes intenté ponerle un dato estático a la consulta tal que así:

```
$result = $conec->query("SELECT * FROM `Teatro` WHERE `indice` = 3");
```

y en el echo si me había regresado correctamente los datos.

Función que inicia todo (el obj es obtenido antes de un JSON):

```
                for (var key in obj){

                    var attrName = key;
                    var attrValue = obj[key];

                    switch(attrName){
                        
                        case "indice":

                            mandaSepara.style.cssText = "text-align: center;";
                            let mandaSeparaBoton = document.createElement("input");
                            mandaSeparaBoton.setAttribute("type", "submit");
                            mandaSeparaBoton.setAttribute("value", "Separar");
                            mandaSeparaBoton.setAttribute("name", attrValue);
                            mandaSeparaBoton.addEventListener("click", function(){
                                separaEvento("Teatro", this.getAttribute("name")); //separarEvento(quien, que)
                            })
                            mandaSeparaBoton.style.cssText = "font-family: castella; font-size: 18px; color: #2E2E2E;";
                            mandaSepara.appendChild(mandaSeparaBoton);

                        break;
```

Comment: por un console.log("entre") debajo del if(fecha > hoy), al parecer no estas entrando alli

Comment: aún no podría saberlo si desde antes no recibo datos u.u no llegará ahí porque no hay fechas

Comment: es la segunda parte de la pregunta, ahí hasta abajo pongo que lo mando a llamar con un send

Comment: tienes razón, lo siento por eso, ya agregué la función que lo llama, en sí es una variable que obtengo del value de un json

Comment: Hice esta variable:             var mandar = "indice=" + que;
            dataT.send(mandar); y edité el php en la pregunta, y ahora me muestra un error 500.

Comment: El error 500 fue por un ";" que no estaba poniendo, pero ahora el php manda un string vacío. Revisé que el id que busca es el mismo id de la base de datos

Comment: Aparentemente, tienes un error al conectar a base de datos, es la única posibilidad de obtener cadena vacía, de lo contrario, recibirías `[]`

Comment: si, ya corregí ese error, ahora estoy recibiendo precisamente esa cadena [ ]

Comment: Estoy preparando una respuesta, dame unos minutos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que garantizar que siempre va a devolver un objeto JSON que pueda analizarse y, de acuerdo a los datos, realizar las acciones correspondientes:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
// Crear un arreglo para devolver como JSON siempre
$ret = [
    'error' => false,  // Especificar si hubo error
    'message' => '',   // Mensaje de error
    'data' => [],      // Conjunto de datos
];

// Asignación ternaria para garantizar que hay un valor
$indice = (isset($_POST['indice'])) ? $_POST['indice'] : '';
if(empty($indice)) {
    $ret['error'] = true;
    $ret['message'] = 'Variable no proporcionada';
} else {
    $conec = new mysqli("","","","");
    if($conec->connect_errno){
        $ret['error'] = true;
        $ret['message'] = 'Error conectando a base de datos';
    } else {
        $result = $conec->query("SELECT * FROM `Teatro` WHERE `indice` = '$indice'");
        if(!$result) {
            $ret['error'] = true;
            $ret['message'] = 'Error en consulta';
        } else {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
                // Agregar filas a data
                $ret['data'][]=$row;
            }
        }
    }
}
// Devolver en formato JSON
echo json_encode($ret);
```

Con esto, siempre vas a recibir en *Javascript* un *JSON* y, de preferencia, usa `fetch()`, es mucho más simple. Asumiendo que la variable se recibe por parámetro en la función donde haces la petición:

```
function llamadaAjax(que) {
    // Crear datos para enviar
    let postData = new FormData();
    // Agregar datos (nombre_de_variable, valor)
    postData.append('indice', que);
    // Ejecutar petición AJAX con fetch
    fetch('comandos/obtenerSingleTeatro.php', {
        method: 'POST',  // Método de envío
        body: postData   // Datos a enviar
    }).then(function(response) {
        // Primer paso, verificar la respuesta y tratar de pasar JSON al siguiente `then`
        if(response.ok) {
            // Respuesta correcta
            return response.json();            
        } else {
            // Esto va a ir directo a `catch`
            throw 'Error en respuesta: ' + response.text();
        }
    }).then(function(result) {
        // Analizar si hay error o no
        if(result.error) {
            // Mostrar error y finalizar
            console.log('Datos no válidos: ' + result.message);
            return;
        }
        // Aquí vamos bien, ya se pueden mostrar los datos
        let fechas = result.data;
        console.log(fechas);
        // ************* IMPORTANTE ****************
        // Revisa la estructura de `fechas` para saber cómo puedes manipular los datos
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // Hubo un error al ejecutar
        console.log('Error en petición AJAX: ' + error);
    });
}
```

**Nota:** Recuerda que tu pregunta está enfocada solo a los valores devueltos por PHP en la petición AJAX y la respuesta solo resuelve ese problema.

En caso de error al recorrer los valores recibidos, te recomiendo crear una nueva pregunta, incluyendo todos los datos necesarios:

- Ejemplo de valores recibidos por AJAX
- Código HTML y Javascript involucrados
- Explicación detallada de:

  - Problema
  - Lo que has intentado
  - Resultado obtenido y resultado esperado

Comment: Muchas gracias, en serio me funcionó perfecto, ya con eso puedo hacer lo que sigue. Ya la puse como respuesta aceptada. En serio gracias